# after deploying the report in VS 2019, always show login prompt

Tags: sql, reporting-services

when deploying reports I am getting login prompt asking for the User Name and password. I have changed the target link. How to solve that.

[prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MamVh.png)

Comment: Can u give us more details, please, like version of server, which report...

Comment: SQL version is 2019 and what do you mean which report?

Answer (score 0):

Look to your browser passwords saved section, re-enter password for your report site or delete it and re-save it when your browser asking you again